# cuxfilter.dashboard.DashBoard.preview keeps throwing "NameError: name 'launch' is not defined" at me

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, coroutine, rapids

### TLDR:

> `await d.preview() # throws "NameError: name 'launch' is not defined"` 
> `# d.preview() # does not throw "NameError: name 'launch' is not defined"; however, it still does not produce the desired image in a jupyter notebook...  It's __repr__ prints` <coroutine object DashBoard.preview at 0x7f44013aaa70>`

---

I'm trying to preview a rapids dashboard that is correctly rendering in a separate browser window.  However, when I try to preview a rasterized screengrab of the dashboard using the convenient looking plotly method, d.preview(), I keep getting this paradoxical exception, "NameError: name 'launch' is not defined".

`await d.preview()` works in the documentation here:

- `https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cuxfilter/stable/themes/Themes.html`

I am running rapids21.08 in python3.7 on ubuntu (Pop!_OS 20.10) using an RTX2080 GPU using a jupyter notebook with the *default* jupyter theme made using `$ jt -r`, and I am not using any matplotlib funny business.  I have run the very common `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` command.

This seems like a really common problem which I'm surprised isn't just working...  Maybe there's something obvious I'm just missing...  Please help me!

The full exception can be found postscript.

Thank you for your time,
Tim

P.S.

> `# d = some cuxfilter.dashboard.DashBoard instance that apparently works with d.show()`
> `await d.preview() # throws NameError: name 'launch' is not defined`

throws

```
 NameError: name 'launch' is not defined 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_8654/2723113380.py in async-def-wrapper()

~/anaconda3/envs/pyenv_ub/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cuxfilter/dashboard.py in preview(self)
    507             port=port, websocket_origin=url, show=False, start=True
    508         )
--> 509         await screengrab("http://" + url)
    510         self.stop()
    511 

~/anaconda3/envs/pyenv_ub/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cuxfilter/assets/screengrab.py in screengrab(url)
      6 
      7 async def screengrab(url):
----> 8     browser = await launch({"slowMo": 5}, args=["--no-sandbox"])
      9     page = await browser.newPage()
     10     await page.setViewport(

NameError: name 'launch' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to the missing pyppeteer package. Installing this in the conda env should resolve the issue:

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge pyppeteer>=0.2.6
```

cuxfilter=21.10 won't have this issue, as the dependency has been added to it.